# insert a if loop in setting key value pair in map reduce spark

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

how to insert a if loop in setting a key in  a spark map reduce.? 
I want that if input word is a starting with uppercase then set it as a key otherwise not
(word count example

sample input - affa Agshs djd Dhh

sample output -

Agshs 1

Dhh 1)

Comment: what you want to insert conditional statement or looping statement ... what is if loop? You can insert anything it... and if you tried something then put your code

Comment: in map reduce I have done         if(word.isUppercase()) context.write();                   how to do this in spark

Comment: @DEEPAKYADAV then you should put down part of the code which have written in map reduce, so that everybody will exactly know what you want to write in spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use **filter()**

**sample_input.txt**

```
affa Agshs djd Dhh
small Capital
Firstbig notFirstBig
```

**spark-shell**

```
val data   = sc.textFile("sample_input.txt")
val filteredData = data.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).filter( w =>  { w.length>0 && Character.isUpperCase(w.charAt(0)) } )
val mapout = filteredData.map(w => (w,1)) 
mapout.foreach(println)
```

**output:**

```
scala> mapout.foreach(println)
(Agshs,1)
(Firstbig,1)
(Dhh,1)
(Capital,1)
```